# Regarding schedule time for sending email

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, jakarta-mail

Need to schedule time for sending email via javamail on Google app engine, I already tried OOP MailScheduler for this but at the end I  am getting error due to it does not support for Google App Engine, it only support to Tomcat, is there any other efficient way to schedule the time for sending emails.

Comment: Maybe you could try to use CRON?

Comment: I've done it using qeues.

Comment: @HubertPopiołkiewicz , cron is used for scheduling mail at defined time or regular interval of time what if i need to send mails to dynamically defined time.

Comment: Follow Floris' comment then.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a task and add to the task queue, you can specify [when this task should be executed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push#the_order_of_task_execution).